# PHPMailer is missing the English Language file

Tags: php, phpmailer

Does anyone here use phpmailer? I downloaded the files for phpmailer 5.2.1 (the newest version I think) and it seems to be missing the english language file. Does anyone have the file or know where I can get it? I'm downloading the files from here: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/branches/phpmailer-2.0/language/phpmailer.lang-en.php